# What is the cleanest way to write this if..then logic?

Tags: c#, coding-style

They both do the same thing.  Is one way better?  Obviously if I write the code I'll know what I did, but how about someone else reading it?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
```

OR

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
   return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
}
```

Comment: It's a side point but I never got the space-after-the-if thing...

Comment: The space between the "if" (and other keywords) and the following "(" helps distinguish the keyword usage from a function call (no space = function call).  In some editors, that space is the only distinction.

Comment: I think that the first one is the cleanest approach. The second uses a double-negative and makes you think that little bit more.

Comment: Oops. Just read a comment further down that points out both have dbl negative!

Comment: This is lame question. I remeber people from my firm staring and pondering 1h+ , how should they modify simple part of 3 lines of code that calculates difference between two dates. OMFG

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? 
            RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall") : 
            Redirect(returnUrl);
```

I prefer that.

Or the alternative:

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)  
            ? RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall")  
            : Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Comment: This is less readable than either of the options listed in the question.

Comment: Only if you're not intimately familiar with the ternary ?: operator.
I personally find it clearer.

Comment: I like it better too (deleted my exactly that same answer)

Comment: IMO, familiarity with the language should be a given, not familiarity with the code. Any common constructs should be obvious to a reader.

Comment: It's not so much the ternary operator.  All the parentheses and the very long line make your code less readable.  But it comes down to a matter of taste.

Comment: I also prefer this style in place of simple if/else constructs.

Comment: One set of parentheses can be remove (first set) and line breaks after ? and : make it much more readable.

Comment: Oh, and I agree on the line breaks :)

Comment: I find it clearer when ? and : are at the beginning of each branch.

Comment: @Ates Goral: Added as an alternative. I tend to agree with you.

Comment: I like it much better with the linebreaks :)

Comment: Matter of opinion, of course, but I prefer to use the ternary operator only for simple assignments. Not so much for controlling major flow in the program.

Comment: Agreed. I think it's also okay for simple return statements like this too.

Comment: I think it's better this way because you're writing less and using a positive assertion at the beginning

Comment: Ternary operator is not acceptable if it spans more than 1 line. You might as well write Perl.

Comment: Splitting it across lines clarifies it. One term per line: Condition, true action, false action. It's not rocket surgery :)

Comment: +1 on splitting so that lines start with operator characters.
-1 for using ternary operator at all.  If this code is surounded by other code it is very hard to notice there is any sort of return happening at all.

Comment: Clarification: Sure, it is very clear that a return is happening (since that is the leading key word), but it feels awkward to bury alternative flow logic in a statement type that is generally used to proved alternative values.

Comment: @Tom A: Horses for courses I guess :) I read it as providing alternative values for the return statement.

Comment: @Tom A: Also, I'd expect this to be the last line in a method.

Comment: @Andrew: Good point -- if it is the last statement then it is clear, and pretty clean.  All in all, it's one of those things that is cool when *you* do it, but annoying when anyone else does.  ;)

Answer (score 24):

I believe it's better to remove the not (negation) and get the positive assertion first:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
   return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
}
else
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

-or-

```
// Andrew Rollings solution
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? 
                    RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall") : 
                    Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Comment: Why is that the *right* way? I much prefer the common case at the top.

Comment: +1 I think the negation is a bigger issue concerning 'cleanliness' then the braces.

Comment: Positive assertion should be at the top.

Comment: I don't know - I prefer the other way:
if (expected case) ... else ...
even if it does add an extra ! operator.

Comment: I believe (and don't quote me on this) but the common case at the top is legacy from the days were processors couldn't optimize the best path (IE poor pipelining) - IMHO it's just not relevant anymore.

Comment: Why should the positive assertion be at the top? Obviously it's a matter of taste, not a fact as you're trying to pass it off as.

Comment: I have to say, I prefer my solution (which is updated from that which you've copied above... Now with added formatting goodness).

Comment: Actually, why copy it at all? It's right there in my answer.. (Not being funny, just puzzled).

Comment: Personally, I think both have their place in this world, thus using both. ;)

Comment: I also had added it before all the edits were done to yours... specifically removing the negation

Comment: Alright :) But if your answer gets accepted because of it, I'm kicking your ass! ;)

Comment: Positive assertions are generally easy to read than negations, which is why they are preferred. If you have a one line 'is null' type of test, then sure, put that first. But, the general rule is aim for positive comparisons.

Answer (score 21):

One style issue:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
}
return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

When you cancel out the double negation it reads a whole lot better, no matter which brace style you choose. Code that reads better is always best ;)

Comment: This also has the advantage (at least in this example) of making the common case the default return.

Comment: I like this one the best, out of all of the variations. It's clean, consistent, obvious and easily readable.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't notice the ! since I thought it was more about the bracing.

Comment: This also follows the pattern to return as soon as possible to keep the program flow clear.

Answer (score 9):

the second way is better, no confusion about what you mean...

Comment: +1 An explicit else is always better for readability by the unfamiliar

Comment: Well, I'd still disagree. Forced to choose between the two I'd pick the first.

Comment: I'm with Andrew. I prefer the guard clause at the top. The 'return' does the work of the 'else'.

Comment: yes of course logically they do the same thing. but the question asked about someone else picking up this code and figuring out what was meant. Its simply a fact: for a random reader, you have a higher chance of confusion using the first version vs the second

Comment: It's certainly not a fact.  I find the first slightly easier to understand.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a fairly small matter of style.  I'd argue that your two samples are equally readable.

I prefer the former, but other people prefer only one exit point from a function and would probably suggest something like:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
   result = Redirect(returnUrl);
}
else
{
    result = RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
}

return result;
```

Comment: I was half through writing that exact code sample.  The single exit point can make for a nasty nested mess of conditionals sometimes.

Comment: I'd argue that single exit point makes for a nasty mess nearly all the time.  I think it's a holdover from trying to tame the use of goto.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you guys.  I meant to point out another common way of writing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 5):

I like the first example because it's more obvious that this excerpt **will** return.  If both `return`s are in indented blocks, it takes just a little more mental effort to tell.

Comment: This was exactly my thoughts.

Comment: That's actually a pretty nice defense for the first example. I intuitively prefer that, but I never really found a way to explain my preference to others. Thanks! +1

Comment: +1 Yes, I always think there is something missing after the closing else }.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the 'double-negative' and use the fully-expanded style.  I am sure most compilers now can suitably optimize the code on your behalf, so no reason to take short-cuts for readability.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the entirety of the method then I'd say the second (using the else) is a bit more elegant. If you have preceding code or (especially) much more code before the return in the else case, I'd say it's better not to put the else. Keeps from code becoming too indented.

i.e. either:

```
void myfunc()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
    }
}
```

or

```
void myfunc()
{
    // ... maybe some code here ...

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
       return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    // ... a bunch of other code ...

    return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code feels messy because of the unavoidable double-negative logic (and shuffling things around isn't going to clear it up). Whichever arrangement you use, I think you should add some comments so that the reader doesn't need to do a double-take:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
  // hooray, we have a URL
  return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
else
{
  // no url, go to the default place
  return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
else
    return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
```

Comment: Hmmmm. For the sake of sustainability, this is something I'd stay away from. It's a good rule, typically, to always enclose these types of statements in braces. Just Google C/C++ coding standards and you'll find this to be a common theme.

Comment: Agreed about using braces. If you ever have to add a line before the return, you'll appreciate having them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a better way... it depend on each developer.  That's why before starting a project you should decide what is the coding standard ...

Answer (score 0):

I like the first better.

```
if ( ) 
{
    return ... 
}
return
```

For me it reads like a "default" you can chain more conditions but at the end there is a default.

Of course it is a matter of style.

Additional question.

Is it C# style to put the square brackets and in a single line?

```
if ( ) 
{
}
else
{
}
```

I have seen this permeated into Java code samples in SO, and I'm wondering this is the root cause.

**EDIT**

@Owen. 
I mean, Is it C# style using this form?

```
if ()  
{
    code ... 
}
else
{
    code...
}
```

Rather than this ( which would be [Java preffered](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc6.html#430) )

```
if ( ) { 
    code ... 
} else { 
   code ...
}
```

I have had some arguments in the past about this, but most of the times, only with people that come from C# background.

Comment: Not necessarily C# style, just good style regardless of the (C-esque) language. See the comments to mbeckish's reply.

Answer (score 0):

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493603/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-write-this-if-then-logic/493618#493618), but more readable:

```
return
  string.isNullorEmpty(returnUrl) ? 
     RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall") :
     Redirect(returnUrl);
```

This way works, is readable and non-redundant.

Answer (score 0):

From a maintenance perspective I prefer the first version. I've seen less errors with a consistent "get out early" style.

The ternary operator (?:) is OK, but only if it is very unlikely that new code will be inserted before the 2nd return statement. Otherwise when the time comes to add something new into the 2nd code path, the ternary statement has to go back to being an if/else block anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When I have only one line sometimes I compact the if statement like this:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) { 
  return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall"); 
}
else{ return Redirect(returnUrl); }
```

Although when I look at it, Andrew Rollings might have the best solution although I had never thought of using it until today.

Answer (score 0):

LFSR's ["else" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493603/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-write-this-if-then-logic/493635#493635) is the most maintainable and readable.

Using a separate `else` clause allows logic to be added without inadvertently changing the flow.  And it's bad enough having multiple exit points without hiding two of them in a single ternary operator statement!

Answer (score -1):

The first one. You don't need any else if you are returning a value inside the if statement. So:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
return RedirectToAction("Open", "ServiceCall");
```

Comment: ewww... wash your mouth out with soap!

Comment: interesting... did you deleted the offending comments? or you're just saying it because of the code I suggest, that btw is how the Linux kernel creator suggest it has to be :)